# How to ngFor on multiple types of components using ngComponentOutlet?

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-component-outlet

I've got a whatsapp-like chat case of many types of messages that are needed to be displayed differently.

Each has its' own component such as `TextMessageComponent`,  `FileMessageComponent`, etc..

I'd like to be able to `ngFor` once on my array of messages without having to `ngIf` over the types.

I've heard `ngComponentOutlet` might be the solution but found it hard to implement..

Any suggestions, a mini demo or anything you find useful would be highly appreciated!

Comment: put both in one array of data, using the controller or view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having a property on the object should help you

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"  style="border: solid 1px; padding: 20px;margin: 20px;">
      <span style="color:red"> {{item.name}} </span>
      <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item.component"><ng-container>
  <br>
</div>
```

Array object should be as

```
items:Array<any> = [
{
  name: 'slider'
  component: sliderComponent

},
{
  name: 'user'
  component: usersComponent

},
{
  name: 'slider'
  component: sliderComponent

},
{
  name: 'alert danger'
  component: AlertDangerComponent
}

]
```

Ensure that all the components are loaded by using them in the AppModule

```
entryComponents: [AlertDangerComponent, AlertSuccessComponent, usersComponent, sliderComponent ]
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/GCL95VxUsW2UTFrp7x07?p=preview)**

Comment: @mayur Thank you. :) :)

Comment: is it somehow possible to pass data into "*ngComponentOutlet"?

Comment: @Benjamin yes it is possible

Comment: Are `sliderComponent` and `usersComponent` types or instances? I'm asking because they are lower-case

Comment: Yes they are component themselves @Simon

Comment: @Aravind how to pass data into *ngComponentOutlet?