# Angular 4 using ngComponentOutlet to display dynamically changing ContentChildren

Tags: angular, typescript

My ultimate goal is to just have a custom container component with a dynamic list of custom card components that are individually accessible (not as a single entity using ng-content).

`<custom-card-holder>
    <custom-card></custom-card>
    <custom-card></custom-card>
    ...
    <custom-card></custom-card>
</custom-card-holder>`

**Ideally I just grab the child components with ContentChildren query and put each one into a styled div inside the custom card holder.**

The displaying each content child individually in the styled div to get it to fit nicely in the holder.

I have tried using TemplateOutlet and a few other odds and ends but the ComponentOutlet seems the most promising.

**I would like to avoid any extra clutter on the code shown above.** I understand the data can just be input and the component can be used inside without any transclusion but that just means a more complex interface for others to figure out.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @yurzui in essence an interface like <ul><li></ul> where the child components are nested rather than created in the parent component. The only difference is its in angular 4 with custom components. The children can all be the same type too

Comment: Can you have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138665/how-to-ngfor-on-multiple-types-of-components-using-ngcomponentoutlet/45138973#45138973)

Answer (score 1):

@Arivinds comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138665/how-to-ngfor-on-multiple-types-of-components-using-ngcomponentoutlet/45138973#45138973) led to fixed a syntax problem and also a semi-workaround for the original issue.

1. The ngComponentOutlet takes a Type/Class not an instance.
2. Nesting the Class in a list with the instance:

   `cardList =  [{ component:CardClass,context:instance}]`

In the end I added a `CardHolder` component which template is just a `<ng-content></ng-content>` and instead of `Card` class I had `CardHolder` in the `cardList`.

Then I used the content property of `ngComponentOutlet` to project my actual `Card` into the `CardHolder`.

```
 cardList:any[] = [
  {
    type:CardHolder,
    context:{}
  }
  ];

`<div #scrollItem class="item" *ngFor="let card of cardList">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="card.type;content: card.context;"></ng-
container>
</div>`
```

**The catch** is that content(ngComponentOutlet) takes a Node so When I query for `ContentChildren` I purposefully grabbed the `ElementRef` and used `nativeElement`. **Note the double square brackets.**

```
`ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.cardList = this.cards.toArray().map((card)=>{
       return {type:CardHolder,context:[[card.nativeElement]]};
    })
 }`
```

Hope this helps anyone in the same boat.

**Note**: The ability to add inputs to dynamic components is supposedly in the works/backlogged but currently not implemented

**Note**: Also I believe any dynamic components must be in the entryComponents array of the NgModule